# CodeIgniter 2.1, PHP, MySQL - select where without some characters

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Is there some way to select one field with select statement, but to disregard some characters. For example:

```
$string = 'first_title_ever';
(original title = First Title, Ever )
SELECT * FROM `article` WHERE 'title' = $string LIMIT 1;
```

If I select via LIKE, if there is title **First Title, Ever 2**, there will be two results and so on. How can I omit some characters and get needed field? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: yes you can. what are the charecters?

Comment: I need to exclude: **,:""**

Comment: good. **1.** Now what have you tried to remove this characters? **2.** On what basis, you are dissociating the above term?

Comment: I have removed **_** from string (with **str_replace**) and replaced it with space (** **). I need to make query which will find article by its title not id (I know that it is a lot simpler to do query via id, but I want clean url).

Comment: **str_replace** also accepts arrays which will solve 1st part. what is the problem on the 2nd part?

Comment: It solves part of the problem. Other part is - if title have commas or other characters (from the first comments) they are removed from the url part with **-**, and latter I cannot return all characters.

Comment: that's why you need to have a pattern. and a character which will be consider as the limiter. this character can not be use in title.

Comment: I see the problem. I guess it will be a lot more simpler to add another field which will contain title in cleaned version and search by that field

Comment: Yes. That. It's usually called a "slug". There's an example of it in the CodeIgniter tutorial in the user guide.